# How to style my radio button just like on mac?

Tags: css

How can I style my radio button to look like the ones on mac using css just like this?
 [image]

Comment: Have you tried installing OSX?

Answer (score 2):

### SOME FUN STUFF

If we are talking about webpages - and not caring about browser suppot much ... there is some exciting things you can do just with CSS:

- `box-shadow`
- `-webkit-` and `-moz-appearance`
- `input[type="radio"]:active:before` or `:after`
- `border-radius`
- `:checked`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tpm4u/3/) -watch out: works only on certain browsers!

You can even go crazier with some `radial-gradient`s and other fancy stuff.

With a little work you might get somethink like this to display similarly on most newer browsers, but I just wanted to point out that there are some ways there.

Something to look forward to being maybe a crossbrowser standard sometime ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot style a radiobutton. What you can do however is hide the actual radiobutton using javascript and replace it with a `span` or `div` that is clickable and changes the checked property of the actual, hidden radiobutton. 
You can then style the `span` or `div` using css.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about websites indeed. Here's a jQuery plugin that will get you a bit on the way http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/jquery-javascript/jquery-fancy-custom-radio-and-checkbox/

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about websites and I assumed that the poster did too since he tagged CSS. Thank you for the addition.

Comment: THIS IS NOT TRUE, you can do it in webkit... you can style radiobutton of course.!!! with CSS3 http://experiments.wemakesites.net/custom-css3-checkboxes-and-radios.html

Answer (score 1):

You can style them as you like and still in an accessible manner by following this tutorial and example: **[Accessible, Custom Designed Checkbox and Radio Button Inputs Styled with CSS (and a dash of jQuery)](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/customInput/)**

Notice how the buttons are still displayed on screen (no `display: none` thus screen readers won't have any problem with the form) but the image (sprite) is above each of them so we can't see the vanilla buttons anymore. You can see the trick by playing with left and top value of the absolutely positioned elements in Firebug.

Or you can also follow the wise advice of @meagar

Answer (score 0):

Man you can use CSS3 to achieve this. is not true that you can't!!

http://experiments.wemakesites.net/custom-css3-checkboxes-and-radios.html